# Дан массив с числами. Числа могут быть положительными и отрицательными. Найдите сумму положительных элементов массива

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = [2, 5, 9, 15, 0, 4];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i]%2 !=1){
        console.log(arr[i]*2)
    }
}
```

Comment: 0 в массиве чисел не подходит под условие задачи "Числа могут быть положительными и отрицательными", а значит это предложение в условии лишнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не ясно зачем вы проверяли число на четность, но если надо положительные, то так:

```js
var arr = [2, 5, 9, 15, 0, 4, -9];
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > 0){
        sum += arr[i];
    }
}
console.log(sum);
```

Либо:

```js
const arr = [2, 5, 9, 15, 0, 4, -9];
console.log(arr.reduce((a, c) => c > 0 ? a + c : a, 0));
```

Comment: во втором варианте отсутствует проверка на положительность

Comment: Делал задания до этого на четность, недочитал, что в этом задание положительность, спасибо за ответы.

Comment: что же вы так сначала спрашиваете, а потом читаете) давайте наоборот

Comment: Простите, утром бывает дико туплю)

Answer (score 0):

**Тоже недавно начал изучать JS и тоже видел эту задачу, сделал её так: **

```js
let arr = [1,2,5,5,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5];
let result = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i] < 0) continue
    else if(arr[i] > 0){
        result += arr[i]
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: UPD: Строку if (arr[i] < 0) continue, можно не писать, чёт затупил

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]